# How to increment std:set iterator by more than one in Cython?

Tags: c++, indexing, set, cython

I have a C++ std:set for which I want to implement "fake" indexing in Cython. Let's say I have an extension type that wraps the set and I want to have a method `get_member(int i)` which returns the ith element in the set. This is what I got, basically iterating over the set using `cython.operator.preincrement` until the desired point is reached and then dereferencing the current iterator position:

```py
# distutils: language = c++

from cython.operator cimport dereference, preincrement
from libcpp.set cimport set as cppset

cdef class SetWrapper:
    
    cdef cppset[int] _set
    
    def __cinit__(self, s: set = None):
        if s is not None:
            self._set = s
    
    cpdef int get_member(self, int i):
        cdef cppset[int].iterator it = self._set.begin()
        cdef int count 
        
        # Would it be possible to increment it directly by i?
        for count in range(i):
            preincrement(it)
            
        return dereference(it)
```

```
test_set = SetWrapper({1, 2, 3})
test_set.get_member(2)
# 3
```

While this works, it seems a bit wasteful to always iterate through the set when it was possible to increment the iterator directly by `i` positions. Is this possible in some way?

PS: Let's put aside the fact that this is not quite what one is supposed to use sets for...

Comment: I don't know anything about cython, but in C++ a `std::set` does not have random access iterators, so you can't advance an iterator more than one element at a time. Advancing such an iterator by 10 elements requires 10 increment operations. `std::next` and `std::advance` look like they let you advance such an iterator more than one element, but for forward iterators they just increment it until the desired distance is traversed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok, thanks. That seems to answer the question then. My background in C++ is not very strong, so I may need to read up on these iterators...

Comment: See `iterator` and `const_iterator` for [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). They are [Bidirectional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) which means they have `operator++` and `operator--` but not `operator+=`, `operator-=`, `opeator+`, `operator-`, `operator[]` or any other operator that lets you skip around quickly.